I am designing my own modular programming language. Am I right on memory management strategy?
To ease memory management in C, I will move OR let all memory allocation of every module of the program into a single function and expect them to be working without problem. I am not sure if it works properly in every scenario..
I will release the memory when the work of module is done automatically.. I won't let manual thread creation as well, it auto-parallelize the code specially the loops..
